# Calculate "cell/sum(cells)" script across hundreds of small sets

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I'm new here, and would greatly appreciate some help with this problem. I'm trying to take a column (Column H in this case) that's split up by blank rows into a few hundred sets of 21 cells each and find the portion of each cell to that set.

[Picture - Objective: Take a cell and divide it against 21 other cells in that set. Skip the blank row and repeat the same process several hundred times.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5SyDw.png)

For example, I want to find out: "In 2015, what portion of Alabama employees were in Management Occupations?" and come to the conclusion that 3.669% were in management (Solution example would be cell [I3]). I want to calculate that for all states across all occupations across all years.

I am currently doing this by typing out what's found in column K to get the solutions found in column I, but that is very laborious and seems inefficient. How would I go about getting solutions found in Column I in the easiest way possible?

Please note that the groups must be broken up by state, which is why there are blank rows between each state.

Thank you very much, and if you need a further explanation of what I'm trying to accomplish, please let me know and I'll respond immediately!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [SUMIF()](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SUMIF-function-169b8c99-c05c-4483-a712-1697a653039b):

```
=H3/SUMIF(C:C,C3,H:H)
```

It will now group the it by the state.

If you want to group it further then use [SUMIFS()](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SUMIFS-function-c9e748f5-7ea7-455d-9406-611cebce642b):

```
=H3/SUMIFS(H:H,C:C,C3,A:A,2015)
```

This will group it by the state and year 2015.

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you so much! The SUMIFS() was exactly what I was looking for! I'm not surprised it was that easy. Cheers!

Comment: @PaulBernert please mark as correct, by clicking the check mark by the answer.  It is something only you can do.  It will mark this question as being answered.